# How to Call awakeFromNib in mainViewController.m

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, xib, custom-cell, awakefromnib

I have an xib file containing a custom cell. I'm trying to access the height of an object created in `customCell.m`.

Here is my code:

`customCell.m`

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    self.label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 200)];
    [self.label setText:@"This is a label"];
    [self.myView addSubview:self.label];

    NSLog(@"%f", self.label.frame.size.height);  // Results: 200.0000
}
```

`mainViewController.m`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    customCell *cellVC = [[cutsomCell alloc] init];

    NSLog(@"%f, %f", cellVC.label.frame.size.height); // Results: 0.0000
}
```

Comment: well, the cell did not awake from nib because it is not created from nib file

Comment: So how do I get it to load in the viewDidLoad method?

Comment: Didn't he write that it comes from a xib file in your question?

Comment: I have a custom cell in the xib file with some items inside. I then programmatically added other items to it via awakeFromNib

Comment: So what is the problem then?

Comment: When I get the height of the label in mainViewController.m, it gives me a height of 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

awakeFromNib is called when all file owners outlets and properties are set.  Things are not wired up (in terms of frames/layout) in viewDidLoad.

awakeFromNib is called after viewDidLoad, that is why you see the difference.

Comment: Is there a way to call it in the viewDidLoad?

Comment: AwakeFromNib is automatically called for you, no need to call it explicitly

Comment: How do I access the items in the awakeFromNib

Comment: Add your views as IBOutles to the cell's file owner ( your view controller usually)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this doesn't work. You are creating your customCell via alloc/init in code. AwakeFromNib is only called for objects defined in a nib file.

You probably need to define your customCell in a separate nib file, and load that nib file through `+ (BOOL)loadNibNamed:(NSString *)aNibName owner:(id)owner` or similar.

Comment: I don't think I'm creating your customCell via alloc/init programmatically. The reason why I have "customCell *cellVC = [[cutsomCell alloc] init];" is because I want to do get the labels height.